# Resource interpretted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, telerik

On our production server(Server 2008 + IIS7) I got the error when loading page

> Resource interpretted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: http://[siteurl]telerik.web.ui.webresources.axd
>
> with Sys is not defined as other error.

We are using Telerik Radmenu (not in GAC) and menu does not appear (although we can inspect in chrome to see its loading content).

Also this is working on my local dev machine.

I've searched web and tried few different ideas, like changing the order of http handler for .axd in web.config, matching my local web.config with production, etc.

Would you please guide in right direction?

Cheers.

Comment: Resolved myself. There is a code block in Global.asax which was cause the issue.